# Values allocation in 4 textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I have 4 textboxes and one label on my form, 4 textboxes represent 4 payment types (cash, card, bank transfer and other payment method).
In my label i have summary value which i increment when i'm adding new item to receipt.

Textbox names are: `cashTbox` `cardTbox` `bankTbox` `otherTbox`
Label name is: `summaryLbl`

By default cashTextbox.text is equal to summ.content and every time I add an item to database i increment `summaryLbl` + `itemPrice` (item price from database).
I have tried making a function which will allow me to subtract from `cashTbox`to other payment types without allowing `cashTbox` to go to negative value.

My code is as follows:

```
 Private Sub cashTbox_LostKeyboardFocus(sender As Object, e As KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs) Handles cashTbox.LostKeyboardFocus
    If sender.IsFocused = True And sender.text.length > 0 Then
        If calculateP(sender) = True Then

        End If
    End If
End Sub

Dim sumP as decimal = summaryLbl.content
Dim cashP as decimal = cashTbox.text
Dim cardP as decimal = cardTbox.text
Dim bankP as decimal = bankTbox.text
Dim otherP as decimal = otherTbox.text

Public Function calculateP(ByVal s As Object)
    Try
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.text) Then
            s.text = "0,00"
        Else
            s.text = Decimal.Parse(s.text)
        End If
        If s Is cashTbox Then

        ElseIf s Is cardTbox Then
            cardP = s.text
            cashTbox.Text = sumP - (cardP + bankP + otherP )
        ElseIf s Is bankTbox Then
            bankP = s.text
            cashTbox.Text = sumP - (cardP + bankP + otherP )
        ElseIf s Is otherTbox Then
            otherP  = s.text
            cashTbox.Text = sumP - (cardP + bankP + otherP )
        End If
        cashTbox.Text = sumP - (cardP + bankP + otherP )
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
 setValues()
    Return True
End Function

Public Function setValues()
    summaryLbl.content = sumP
    cashTbox.text = cashP
    cardTbox.text = cardP
    bankTbox.text = bankP
    otherTbox.text = otherP
End Function
```

Comment: Try using `Option Strict On` and fixing the errors that are displayed.

Comment: This is a WPF application. Yes?

Comment: @Mary yes it is

Comment: You told us what you were doing, but could you also tell us what your problem is?

Comment: Once you set Option Strict on and fix all the type mismatches, you will immediately get the dreaded NRE (Null Reference Exception) unless you have set content and text properties at design time. You can't assign values to your fields until the user has a chance to fill in the boxes.